# simplest way to get SPUser or SPGroup From ID in sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

i am stuck to an issue where i have a List ID  - list of Ids i have to find the LoginName of  SPUser or SPGroup with the id in the ListID

i tried the following but it threws exception  as it did not find user when group id is there

```
              foreach (var id in ID)
                {
                    SPUser spUser = web.SiteUsers.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(id));
                    if (spUser != null)
                    {
                        lstUsers.Add(spUser.LoginName);
                         continue;
                    }
                    SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(id ));
                    if (spGroup != null)
                    {
                        lstGroups.Add(spGroup.LoginName);
                         continue;

                    }

                }
```

please suggest what to do !!!

Comment: I'm confused...What is `ID`? What users are you trying to get? Any user with permissions on each list item?

Comment: Noops when i fetch collection from  a Person or Group type column Using sharepoint entity model it will retun List<int?>UserIds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest two changes.

1. Use `SPFieldUserValue`. It doesn't throw an exception if user doesn't
   exist.
2. Use the `SPGroupCollection.GetCollection(int[] ids)`

   ```
   SPUserCollection users = web.SiteUsers;
   SPGroupCollection groups = web.SiteGroups;
   foreach (var id in ID)
   {
     // try to get user-name
     SPUser spUser = new SPFieldUserValue(web, Convert.ToInt32(id), null).User;
     if (spUser != null)
     {
       lstUsers.Add(spUser.LoginName);
       continue;
     }
     // try to get group-name
     var foundGroups = groups.GetCollection(new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(id) });
     if (foundGroups.Count > 0) 
     {
       lstGroups.Add(foundGroups[0]);
       continue;
     }
     // If execution reaches this point: Nothing found with this id
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If i read your question correct: You have list called `ID` in which you have numeric ids (user and group ids) and you want to add the name of the user or group corresponding to the id to an other list (called lstUsers or lstGroups).

The exception is to be expected if the id being handled is the id of a group. The function `web.SiteUsers.GetById()` throws an exception when the given id is not found and that is what you try first. Try wrapping it in a `try-catch`-block.

**Bonus:** store SiteUsers and SiteGroups in a variable, to avoid getting this infomation over and over again from the database in each iteration of the loop.

```
SPUserCollection users = web.SiteUsers;
SPGroupCollection groups = web.SiteGroups;
foreach (var id in ID)
{
  // try to get user-name
  try{
    SPUser spUser = users.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(id));
    if (spUser != null)
    {
      lstUsers.Add(spUser.LoginName);
      continue;
    }
  }catch(Exception){
     //  no user found with id.
  }

  // try to get group-name
  try {
    SPGroup spGroup = groups.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(id ));
    if (spGroup != null)
    {
      lstGroups.Add(spGroup.LoginName);
      continue;
    }
  }catch(Exception){
     // no group found with id
  }

  // If execution reaches this point: Nothing found with this id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... but want to ask is there any  other better option - i  got a suggestion to read XML of **web.SiteUsers** . i want to know which one is better approach